# On click reusable function just javascript

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning javascript first stages.   What I am trying to achieve is to click the roll dice button and the dice to show a number between 1 and 6.  I have got that to work but I cannot get it to work after the first click. I have tried loops in the function etc.  I am very new to javascript sorry if its a silly question guys. :)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Learn Javascript</title>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <style type="text/css">
  body {font-family: sans-serif; margin:0; padding:0; background-color:#ddd; }
  #holder {margin:0 auto; width:150px; text-align:center;} 

  #number { margin:0 auto; height:100px; width:100px; background-color: #fff; border-radius: 5px; text-align:center;
   display: flex;
   justify-content: center;
   align-items: center;
   flex-direction: column;
   border:1px solid black;
   font-family: arial;
  }

  input {margin:20px; width:75px; font-weight: bold;}
 </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Javascript Dice Roll</h1>

<div id="holder">
 <div id="number">
  <p id="diceNumber" style="font-size: 50px;">- -</p>
 </div>

 <input type="button" name="dice role" onclick="rollTheDice()" value="Roll Dice!">

</div>


<script>

 var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 ) + 1;

function rollTheDice(){

  document.getElementById("diceNumber").innerHTML = dice;
 }



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to generate one **random** number **every** time you clicked the button.

```js
function rollTheDice(){
     var dice = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6 ) + 1;
     document.getElementById("diceNumber").innerHTML = dice;
}
```

```html
<h1>Javascript Dice Roll</h1>

<div id="holder">
 <div id="number">
  <p id="diceNumber" style="font-size: 50px;">- -</p>
 </div>

 <input type="button" name="dice role" onclick="rollTheDice()" value="Roll Dice!">

</div>
```

Comment: So basically the var dice. is to be written inside the function it self?  Thanks  Alexandru. :)

Comment: @AaronNewsum, yes.